# Numbering convention for the linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, version, conventions

What is the convention for numbering the linux kernels? AFAIK, the numbers never seem to decrease. However, i think I've seen three kinds of schemes

- 2.6.32-29
- 2.6.32-29.58
- 2.6.11.10

Can anybody explain what are the interpretations of these numbers and formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.6.32-29: 2.6.32: base kernel, -29 final release by ubuntu

2.6.32-29.58: 2.6.32: base kernel, -29.58 ongoing release (-29) by ubuntu

2.6.11.10: 2.6.11: base kernel, .10 tenth patch release of it. (2.6.11 was chosen by volunteers (read Greg KH) to be a "long term maintenance" release).

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by ongoing release? what exactly does 58 represent?

Comment: From Ubuntu kernel wiki page: "The kernel package version is of the following form 2.6.35-6.9. The numbers before the - represent the base upstream version from which this kernel was forked, the first number following the - represents the ABI number, the final number is an upload number." https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ

Answer (score 7):

"Linux kernel version numbering" at wikipedia: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Version_numbering